# Map many tables with one to many relation to a single object

Tags: .net, one-to-many, fluent-interface, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to figure out how to map the following database tables to my domain model using Fluent API. Is it at all possible?

What I have in the database:

```
table Person
{ Id
  Name
  Surname }

table Contact
{ Id
  PersonId
  ContactType
  ContactDesc }

e.g. of the data: 
Person {Id: 1, Name: "John", Surname: "Sutherland"}
Contact {Id: 1, PersonId: 1, ContactType: "Work", ContactDesc: "000 0000 000"}
Contact {Id: 2, PersonId: 1, ContactType: "Home", ContactDesc: "000 0000 001"}
Contact {Id: 3, PersonId: 1, ContactType: "Cell", ContactDesc: "000 0000 002"}
```

My Domain Model:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string WorkTelephoneNumber { get; set; }
  public string HomeTelephoneNumber { get; set; }
  public string CellphoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I'm using Fluent to map to separate Person and Contact POCO's and then manually flattening it into my Domain model. I'm trying to get rid of the additional POCO layer and map straight to my domain model.

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: The mapping to `contact` is a problem as it is not a one to one mapping. It will take a join query to map. Wonder whether model binder supports that. Can you use store procedure or query instead to map? That will be easier.

Comment: I can use a Stored Proc or View but don't want to diverge from the approach I've followed so far. Want to try and utilize EF as much as possible and avoid modifying the persistence/storage layer as far as possible.

Comment: I mean use EF with store proc like `var person = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<Person>( "PersonProc @p0", userId);`

Comment: Sorry, by modifying the persistence/storage layer I mean I'm not keen to touch the database, even if it's just compiling new stored procedures. Would it also mean I'd have to create sp's for get, del, put and post? Using a view is also a possibility. Thank you for the suggestion though, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: You can use SP or direct query. For insert, update, delete there is no direct mapping that you can do with store proc with code first. This was possible with model first edmx. For these operations you may have to use some thing [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-4-1-using-stored-procedure-to-insert-data.aspx). I understand that you want to avoid touching direct database. Because your mapping looked complex to me. I though of putting a comment in case there is no answer.